Azure Data Factory - Timeout error in Copy data action
I am facing the error below when performing the copy data action in ADF:
Type=System.TimeoutException,Message=The operation timed out.,Source=Npgsql

When I enter the source database (local) and preview the data, it appears perfectly. Then I select a database in the cloud (which is where I want to populate tables).
When debugging it gives this error. So it's not a connection error with the local bank (I'm using SHIR).
I've already tried putting CommandTimeout, ConnectionTimeout, Data Pooling and nothing worked...
Connection timeout como 600, CommandTimeout como 0


Type=System.TimeoutException,Message=The operation timed out.,Source=Npgsql

According to the error you are trying to copy data from on-premises PostgreSQL to Azure PostgreSQL server. As you mentioned you don't have any issue from on-premises server issue may be with Cloud server, so ensure your linked service   test connection is successful as shown below:

If the doesn't have from cloud server side, then try to  increase Timeout  of Copy Data Activity.

For more information you can refer the similar question in SO.
